# python and anaconda are in separate paths?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, pip, anaconda

I have a mac/linux system and I'm trying to install pygame but I'm running into the issue where it is installing correctly in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, but not in `/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python`

Is it safe for me to just move/make a copy of site-packages into anaconda3/bin/python? And how do I configure so that in the future if I use `pip install` it will install into anaconda3 instead? Is it because anaconda3 is in /Applications instead of /Library?

Thanks!

Comment: you have *two different python installations on your computre*. "anaconda" **is Python*, it is a CPython distribution that comes with a bunch of third-party libraries. You should probably just install pygame to the correct python and don't just copy-and-paste site-packages folders.

Comment: Also, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` is your system Python on Mac OS, I'm pretty sure, you really shouldn't touch it.